# How can I resume a stopped job in Linux?

Tags: linux, sh, job-control

How can I resume a stopped job in Linux?  I was using emacs and accidentally hit ctrl-z which blasted me back to the console.  I can see it when I type 'jobs'

```
[*****]$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 emacs test_queue.cpp
```

Comment: This is actually a fairly normal work flow for Vim, if you want to keep you commands in your bash history, then you hit `Ctrl-z` type your commands and then resume. Obviously you can run commands without leaving Vim via the `:!` ed command

Answer (score 520, accepted):

The command `fg` is what you want to use. You can also give it a job number if there are more than one stopped jobs.

Comment: for reference, fg is "foreground". You can also continue the job in the background with "bg".

Comment: _You can also give it a job number_ --> Simply doing `fg 1` doesn't work, the syntax is `fg %1`

Answer (score 344):

The general job control commands in Linux are:

- **jobs** - list the current jobs
- **fg** - resume the job that's next in the queue
- **fg %[number]** - resume job [number]
- **bg** - Push the next job in the queue into the background
- **bg %[number]** - Push the job [number] into the background
- **kill %[number]** - Kill the job numbered [number]
- **kill -[signal] %[number]** - Send the signal [signal] to job number [number]
- **disown %[number]** - disown the process(no more terminal will be owner), so command will be alive even after closing the terminal.

That's pretty much all of them.  Note the % infront of the job number in the commands - this is what tells kill you're talking about jobs and not processes.

Comment: I avoid "kill %1" because mistyping it as "kill 1" is really really bad :)

Comment: @barrycarter That's very true.  I usually do an `fg` and a `Ctrl-C` ;)

Comment: @barry: Which is why init in Upstart ignores SIG{TERM,KILL} by default.

Comment: And, of course, "never run as root" ;)

Comment: Why use "%" character. Is it required to be prepended before the job number or Is it a unix convention to specify the int type ?

Comment: @Talespin_Kit I have no idea why the commands require the % character. It was a design choice by the first person to implement the commands, either working at AT&T or one of the Berkeley BSD programmers many decades ago.

Comment: To the list of commands, you can also add `nohup`.

Answer (score 55):

You can also type `%<process_name>`; i.e., you hit Ctrl-Z in emacs, then you can type `%emacs` in the console and bring it back to the foreground.

Comment: Very good to know

Answer (score 37):

Just to add to the other answers, *bash* lets you skip the `fg` if you specify a job number.

For example, these are equivalent and resume the latest job:

```
%
%%
fg
fg %
```

These resume job #4:

```
%4
fg 4
```

Comment: While this is kind of cool, I still find it easier to type `fg` than `%`.

Comment: `%` is awesome, thanks! As a touch-typist, I find `fg` very irritating (same finger). But then, so is `cd`.

Comment: And you can start it in the background with either `bg %` or just `% &`.

Comment: in my case when i tried to use fg i see the stopped process appears and disappears quickly and just <fg %> succeeded to restore it.

Answer (score 33):

If you didn't launch it from current terminal, use `ps aux | grep <process name>` to find the process number (pid), then resume it with:

```
kill -SIGCONT <pid>
```

(Despite the name, `kill` is simply a tool to send a signal to the process, allowing processes to communicate with each other. A "kill signal" is only one of many standard signals.)

Bonus tip: wrap the first character of the process name with `[]` to prevent the `grep` command itself appearing in the results. e.g. to find `emacs` process, use `ps aux | grep [e]macs`

Comment: This also works if you disown a stopped process

Comment: can you also get access to its input/output as it happens when you say `fg` ?

Comment: This is a much more flexible approach than working with job number. Thumbs up.

Comment: Shorter still: `kill -SIGCONT $(pgrep <process name>)`

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who wants to continue **all** suspended processes.

*I don't know how but I achieved several times to completely lock my screen. When I check the processes there are dozens that are suspended. So I continued all processes to unlock my screen.*

Switch to text console with `Ctrl-Alt-F3` or similar. Log in, then issue:

```
ps ax|grep " T"| awk '{print $1}' |grep -v PID | xargs echo kill -SIGCONT
```

- `ps` lists all processes
- `grep` finds mostly only suspended processes (dirty hack, improve?)
- `awk` fetches only first column, PID
- `grep` removes header "PID"
- `xargs` executes a command on the input given
- `echo`  shows command instead of executing
- `kill -SIGCONT` sends signal to continue the process

Output is something like this:

```
kill -SIGCONT 214191 334813
```

Either remove `echo`, cut & paste or pipe the output through `bash` to actually execute it.